# Mouse/Touchpad Failing

Tags: cursor

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a Dell Precision 7510.

Several days ago my pointer started acting up in several ways - dragging icons unexpectedly, not responding to clicks, etc. though the pointer itself would remain responsive.  This is true with both the mouse and touchpad.  Sometimes it seems as if there's just a huge lag.  I don't know.  Gets to the point that I have to power off the machine because warm booting is not possible, nothing is.

At times I can hit Esc to get it going again (tried that just on a lark), but mostly I need to hard boot.  Just now it happened and letting the system sleep for a few minutes revived it.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Afterthought:
I've got dual boot and will try Windows to see what happens.

Comment: Windows has no issue with the cursor on this machine, so I'd say it's definitely an Ubuntu thing.